# breakpoint in php code ignored by Xdebug

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, vim, xdebug

I'm using vim and [Vdebug](https://github.com/joonty/vdebug) (which uses [Xdebug](http://xdebug.org/)) to debug PHP code.

I'm trying to accomplish the following:

1. Put a breakpoint in a PHP file.
2. Call a function in that PHP file from an HTML page using javascript.
3. Break at the breakpoint in the above PHP file.

The above only works if i call the PHP function using another PHP function.
The breakpoint is ignored when i call the PHP function using an ajax request.

Any and all help is most welcomed.

Comment: Are you sure your AJAX request is including the correct cookies?

Comment: @edmondscommerce Which cookies should it include? The request is handled correctly and the response from the server side is as expected.

Comment: I'm talking about this. By using AJAX you are implying using a browser so you generally need to install an xdebug helper extension to provide the correct cookie for Xdebug: http://xdebug.org/docs/remote

Comment: @edmondscommerce It works, Thanks ! If you would add your comment as an answer, i'd be happy to mark it as the correct answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure you are setting the correct Xdebug cookie for your browser based testing.

The easiest way to do this is to use an Xdebug helper plugin for your browser.

Full documentation here:
http://xdebug.org/docs/remote